# Qinggong Monk Lvl 20 Build

Tags: pathfinder-1e, feats, optimization, monk

While I know monks are not optimal characters as there are other class that easily outshine them I built this character to loosely resemble Iron Fist from Marvel. The idea of the build is to be a monk who can fight unarmed effectively while making the most use of his ki pool to deal extra damage. I also wanted to make sure his feats help support his ability to hit as much as possible each round.

I also asked [Extra attacks based on feats](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/96940/extra-attacks-based-on-feats/) to which i received a great thought out answer.

**What I really would like to know is what other 9 feats could I take to increase my ki powers, add more attacks per round, or maximize damage based on existing model?**

I have included the character sheet for what I have so far:

[image: character sheet pg1]
[image: Character sheet pg2]
[image: Character sheet pg3]

*(click for full images)*

Comment: Do you want to consider other things the Iron Fist might do than deal damage? For instance, Dazzling Display and Shatter Defenses are very much within what he'd do in combat besides punching and kicking poor goons.

Comment: @ifusaso I'm am completely open to stuff like that which is why i traded in so many of the monk feats for ki powers like dragon breath, ice cold strike, and scorching ray.

Answer (score 1):

In order to make a character that feels like the Iron Fist Danny Rand, I would take these feats:

- [Intimidating Prowess](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/intimidating-prowess-combat-final/); Danny definitely uses his strength to intimidate when he feels it necessary
- [Weapon Focus](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/weapon-focus-combat-final/) (unarmed strikes); Pre-req and generally useful to deal more damage by landing more hits
- [Dazzling Display](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/dazzling-display-combat/); The Iron Fist's showmanship is known to end fights
- [Shatter Defenses](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/shatter-defenses-combat-final/); Once a target knows they will be beaten, they are already beaten. Also more damage because more hits land
- [Power Attack](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/power-attack-combat-final/); More damage, and you're already reducing enemies' AC against you, so the penalty won't be crippling.
- [Dazing Assault](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/dazing-assault-combat/); Danny strikes to leave his opponents off balance. More Medusa's Wrath for more damage, only use when you know you can hit despite the penalty
- [Cornugon Smash](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/cornugon-smash-combat/); Sometimes Danny simply hits harder than the enemy was prepared for. Synergism with other build suggestions
- [Mobility](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/mobility-combat-final/); Danny will always put himself in the optimal position to strike from, and usually gets there safely
- [Disorienting Maneuver](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/disorienting-maneuver/); Danny uses his body to leave opponents open. More synergism with the build

An aside, based on my recommended build, I would try to move more skill points into Intimidate.

Comment: Thanks a lot a really useful answer. I didn't drop a lot into intimidate just because he seems like to cool calm and collected a person to try to intimidate an enemy.

Comment: Fair enough. I'm basing this primarily on the Marvel collab with Netflix as I've never read the comics. He's usually calm and collected, but he definitely uses intimidation a few times when he gets riled up. Also note that, especially with these feats, Intimidate is more of a show of prowess that causes enemies to make fearful mistakes or give up, more so than the Barbarian's version which is 'bellow at them'.